# How to include CMS page,static blocks into Magento search

Tags: magento-1.4

We have a magento store which mainly features the contents and it has only 12 - 15 products. So client wants cms page and static block content also to be included on search. I can search only under cms page or static block by using like and getcollection methods. But i cant be successful with combining product search/cms page search.

Please can someone help me with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include CMS pages in default magento search we could use the below extension

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tangkoko/extension/1218/tangkoko--fidesio-cms-search
```

I hope, it helps you.

Comment: 6 years later but the link is broken.